# Chrome tabs showing wrong page

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

I have a problem with Google Chrome where occasionally when switching to a newly created tab (usually one made from opening a link into a new tab), the wrong page shows. The correct page is functional, links and other functions are present, but I cannot see them because Chrome seems to be reading the page I want but showing another. Sometimes it is identical to the tab I just left, sometimes it shows the content of a previously closed tab. The problem sorts out when I switch to another tab and back, and then the correct page shows.

This happens fairly often and is rather annoying. Some of my friends have also experienced this, and have stopped using Chrome because of it. If anybody else has seen this problem and happens to know a fix, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What operating system? I've never seen this behavior, and I've been a Chrome user for ages. Are you sure you're not just looking in the wrong tab because the one you just opened did so in a place you didn't expect? Do you have any extensions which "help" with tab management?

Comment: I have the same issue. I use Windows Vista OS. And no, we are clicking the correct tab, it just shows the wrong thing. In my case it shows a tab that was previously closed. As the original poster stated, it can be corrected by switching to a different tab and switching back. It does happen very often, practically every time I use Chrome.

Comment: I have this problem too. It's annoying. I'm considering going back to firefox because of it.

Comment: I have this same problem in Windows Vista and I have no tab related extensions (the only extension is Evernote Web Clipper and it happened before I installed it too). I've noticed that resizing the browser also makes it display the page correctly.

Comment: I've just solved this issue by installing the latest graphic card drivers.

Comment: I was searching for a related problem when I came across this page. For me, loading a page on a new tab always flickers (temporarily displays) the contents of the last visited tab before loading the page. I don't know if this is related, but I believe the bug was raised [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310460).

Comment: This started to happen recently for Linux users with Intel GPUs, see [Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516679).